# mod_rewrite: Rewriting / to cgi script

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, cgi, virtualhost

I have a vhost in which I would like to rewrite / to something like /cgi-bin/script?123. I thought something like this would work, but this rewrites to "/index.html/ somehow.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /cgi-bin/script.cgi?123 [L]
```

How can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /cgi-bin/script.cgi?123 [L]
```

Comment: Strange. With that, it returns the correct document, but the URL itself isn't rewritten; it stays the same!

Comment: Hi Jens,  So is that what you are looking for?  If not, could you give me a couple of examples of input and output you are looking for?  Are you trying to redirect the user to a different page or are you trying to define the exact script that gets triggered/loaded when they go to a particular site/url?

Comment: I just want to (silently) redirect "abc.de[/]" to "abc.de/cgi-bin/script.cgi?123"

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that you want to keep the URL the same but load a different page.  If you want to redirect the user's browser to another page, change "[L]" to "[R=302,L]".  I put a 302 redirect in there as an example but you should determine if that is really the correct one to use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. There was some problem with reply notifications, sorry for high latency :)